# How to offer free version of iOS app to select users?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app with In-App purchase to unlock full version. Is it possible to offer a free In-App purchase upgrade for select users?

Comment: if users get an unlock key for their purchase you could just give them a free key

otherwise you will have to track unique App Ids on your server or sth and then you can set the account type in your backend

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on what you are trying to do. For instance for marketing purposes Apple grants you 100 promo codes you can give to people for free.

You can read about it in the iTunes Connect documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html